# Automatically launch apps on device boot

Tags: android, kotlin

I think I've run the app foreground after booting, but I want to put the app on the screen

It's strange because I can't speak English, so I used a translator..

I don't know because I searched all the codes on Google and combined them.

I want the app to run automatically.

I keep searching on Google, but I don't know.

MainActivity

```
package study.lim


import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.Service
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.IBinder
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat

class MyReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Log.d("Test", "Receive : ${intent.action}")

        val intent = Intent(context, MyService::class.java)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context.startForegroundService(intent)
        } else {
            context.startService(intent)
        }
    }
}

class MyService : Service() {
    companion object {
        const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 10
        const val CHANNEL_ID = "my_notification_channel"
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Log.d("Test", "MyService is started")

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            createNotificationChannel()
            val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("MyService is running")
                .setContentText("MyService is running")
                .build()
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
            CHANNEL_ID,
            "MyApp notification",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        )
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true)
        notificationChannel.lightColor = Color.RED
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true)
        notificationChannel.description = "AppApp Tests"

        val notificationManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(
            Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(
            notificationChannel)
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }
}


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)



        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        var tv_sendMsg = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.tv_sendMsg)

        button.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this,SubActivity::class.java) // 서브화면으로 이동하기 위한 인텐트 객체 생성
            intent.putExtra("msg",tv_sendMsg.text.toString()) //입력 받은 텍스트 값을 담은 뒤 msg라는 키로 잠궜다.
            startActivity(intent)
        }

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.622" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tv_sendMsg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="디바이스 번호"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.642" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />


    <application

        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_pp"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_pp_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Lim"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".SubActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".MyService" />



    </application>

</manifest>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW2dL.png)

Comment: I hope that a stock Android won't allow that. Imagine starting your device, and an app just popping up immediately. Android usually protects their users against shenanigans like that.